# How do I save metadata to a Tensorflow Keras model in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, metadata

I'm looking for a way to save metadata about a model to the model file itself.

For example, I built a model where the same model architecture can be used for two different segmentation problems.  One has 2 classes, one has 4 classes.  Their output handling is slightly different based on which model type it is.  I can figure out the model type by reading the number of classes, but this is a very unsatisfactory solution.

I tried

```
    backend.set_value(model.add_weight(name="ModelType", trainable=False), model_type)
```

but apparently that doesn't get saved in the model file when I run model.save(), as it isn't present when I load the model back in.

If I set trainable=True, without specifying any kind of gradient, I get an exception when training the model.

I could probably encode the model type in the model name, but that seems kind of hacky and doesn't support values more complicated than a few string fields.